# Splitting field and Galois group of a quintic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

On an old algebra prelim, there is a particular problem I would like some help on. It is a five-part question. Let $K$ be the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $$f(x)=x^5- x^4 + x^3 - x^2 +x -1 \text{.}$$ (a) What are the possible values for the minimum degree among the irreducible factors of a polynomial of degree $5$?
(b) Write $f$ as the product of factors irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.
(c) Write $f$ as the product of factors irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
(d) What is the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?
(e) What is the Galois group of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Here's what I tried:
(a) Case 1: For a general quintic polynomial that is reducible (certainly $f$ factors, thanks to my TI-89), it may split into a product of a linear factor (degree $1$) and an irreducible quartic factor (degree $4$) $\textbf{or}$ a product of a linear factor and two irreducible quadratic factors (each of degree $2$) $\textbf{or}$ a product of two linear factors each of degree $1$ and an irreducible cubic factor (degree $3$).
Case 2: A quintic polynomial could also split into a product of three linear factors each of degree $1$ and an irreducible quadratic factor (degree $2$) $\textbf{or}$ a product of an irreducible cubic factor (degree $3$) and an irreducible quadratic factor (degree $2$).
Case 3: Finally, a quintic polynomial can also split into a product of five linear factors each of degree $1$ $\textbf{or}$ the quintic polynomial might already be irreducible of degree $5$.
I think a shorter answer would just be to consider the partitions of $5$, correct?

(b) I got the following for this: $$f(x)= (x-1)(x^2 -x +1)(x^2 +x +1) \text{.}$$

(c) Would this be the same as (b)?

(d) I'm not sure what it should be here, but I'm certain that $5$ is not the solution. Is the degree of the extension $10$?

(e) Having some difficulty with choosing the right automorphisms that permute the roots. At the moment, all I can say is that it will be a subgroup of $S_5$, is that right?

I would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac{x^6-1}{x+1}\qquad$ See [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're getting at. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Certainly the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_{5}$ - there are five roots to permute! Any automorphism of $K$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ must fix $1$. Hence, the Galois group is in fact a subgroup of $S_{4}$. Now think about maps swapping the roots of each irreducible quadratic.

Comment: Is the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3},\sqrt{-3})$, where $\zeta_{n}$ is an $n$-th primitive root of unity?

Comment: Yes. But have you written out $\zeta_3$ explicitly? And therefore $\zeta_6$?